# ID dynamic document firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

How can I make the ID of this document in firestore `QEoevSjHlswgk44nVTsr` dynamic, that is, change according to the IDs in that collection? I'm using angularfire2: ^5.0.0-rc.11

This is what I have:

**firebase.service.ts**

```
proyectos: Observable<Proyecto[]>;

getImagenDestacada() {
    this.proyectos = this.afs.collection('proyectos').doc('QEoevSjHlswgk44nVTsr').collection('archivos', ref => ref
    .orderBy('nombre','asc').limit(1)
    ).snapshotChanges().pipe(map(actions => {
      return actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Proyecto;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id; 
        return { id, ...data };
      });
    }));
    return this.proyectos
    }
```

========================

I have tried the following:

**firebase.service.ts**

```
getImagenDestacada(id:string) {
this.proyectos = this.afs.collection('proyectos').doc(id).collection('archivos', ref => ref
.orderBy('nombre','asc').limit(1)
).snapshotChanges().pipe(map(actions => {
  return actions.map(a => {
    const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Proyecto;
    const id = a.payload.doc.id; 
    return { id, ...data };
  });
}));
return this.proyectos
}
```

**portafolio.component.ts**

```
archivos: Observable<Proyecto[]>;

this.archivos = this.fs.getImagenDestacada(this.id);
```

But I get the following error:

> Error: Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type string, but it was: undefined

Comment: The error is telling you `this.id` is undefined. Make sure it's being set to a string before you call `getImagenDestacada()`.

Comment: I have the id set as string `id: string` I can actually access the IDs of the collection `proyectos` I can print them in the console, but I do not know how I can define it for `getImagenDestacada()` It will be because it is a subcollection?

Comment: `id: string` just means you are creating a variable that is expecting to hold a string. It is the same as doing `id: string = undefined;`.

Comment: Do you have any reference or example of how I can better understand this? I would appreciate.

Comment: Where are you setting `this.id` in portafolio.component.ts?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: const id = a.payload.doc.id.toString();

Answer (score 0):

The error is because when you called

```js
this.proyectos = this.afs.collection('proyectos').doc(id).collection ...
```

`id` is undefined, because `this.id` was undefined in the caller.

According to [the Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data), if you want a dynamically generated id then you can simply leave the parameter blank, ie. change that line to be :

```js
this.proyectos = this.afs.collection('proyectos').doc().collection ...
```

Then Firebase will generate an ID for you.

If, on the other hand, there is a specific ID you want the record to have, then you need to have some code to get that ID for you and pass that through to your `getImagenDestacada` function instead of `this.id`.