# How to show a subСollection when navigating to a specific document in Firestore

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I have a collection on Firestore inside it there are documents, they are displayed in the `RecyclerView` in my application, how can I make it so that when this document is clicked, its subcollection opens?

When you click on a document, the following happens:

```
    private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private final CollectionReference collectionReference = firebaseFirestore.collection("Items");

    AdapterFactoryKeysSnap adapterFactoryKeysSnap;
    RecyclerView rv_keys_factory;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager RLM_keys_factory;
    ProgressBar pb_keys_factory;

    private void RecyclerViewFactory() {
        Query query = collectionReference.orderBy("TurnKeyFactory", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ItemKeys> firestoreRecyclerOptions = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<ItemKeys>()
                .setQuery(query, ItemKeys.class).build();

        adapterFactoryKeysSnap = new AdapterFactoryKeysSnap((ClickKeysBlanc) getContext(), getContext(), firestoreRecyclerOptions);
        rv_keys_factory = requireView().findViewById(R.id.rv_keys_factory);
        RLM_keys_factory = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        SnapHelper snapHelper = new GravitySnapHelper(Gravity.START);
        snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(rv_keys_factory);
        rv_keys_factory.setHasFixedSize(false);
        rv_keys_factory.setLayoutManager(RLM_keys_factory);
        rv_keys_factory.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
        rv_keys_factory.setAdapter(adapterFactoryKeysSnap);
        adapterFactoryKeysSnap.startListening();
        pb_keys_factory = requireView().findViewById(R.id.pb_keys_factory);
        Objects.requireNonNull(rv_keys_factory.getAdapter()).setStateRestorationPolicy(RecyclerView.Adapter.StateRestorationPolicy.PREVENT_WHEN_EMPTY);
        pb_keys_factory.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

The application understands which document was clicked due to "TurnKeyFactory". Inside this document is a subСollection called "TheKeyOpens".

I found a way to implement what was conceived inside this document, I write the following

"Factory exit key(Factory)"- name document

```
    private final FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private final CollectionReference collectionReference = firebaseFirestore.collection("Items").document("Factory exit key(Factory)").collection("TheKeyOpens");
```

The whole problem is that after I write this, it appears in all documents of the main collection, not in the specific selected.

I thought that if my application opens the selected document by "TurnKeyFactory" it will work if I write like this:

```
    private final FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private final CollectionReference collectionReference = firebaseFirestore.collection("Items").document("TurnKeyFactory").collection("TheKeyOpens");
```

But it didn't work.Help solve the problem.

Need to

```
Items->
    - Factory exit key(Factory)->
        - TheKeyOpens->
            -TheKeyOpens 1
            -TheKeyOpens 2
            -TheKeyOpens 3
    - TurnKeyFactory: “1”

    - Factory exit key(Customs)->
        - TheKeyOpens->
            -TheKeyOpens 1
            -TheKeyOpens 2
            -TheKeyOpens 3
    - TurnKeyFactory: “2”
```

[image][image]

Comment: Instead of describing how your database looks like, please edit your question and add a screenshot of it.

Comment: @AlexMamo I have added screenshots and updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought that if my application opens the selected document by "TurnKeyFactory" it will work if I write like this:

```
private final FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
private final CollectionReference collectionReference = firebaseFirestore
    .collection("Items")
    .document("TurnKeyFactory")
    .collection("TheKeyOpens");
```

This reference doesn't work because you are passing an incorrect ID to the document() method. The ID of the document should be "Factory exit key(Factory)" as seen in the screenshot and **not** "TurnKeyFactory" as you actually added. In order to make it work, please use the following reference:

```
private final CollectionReference collectionReference = firebaseFirestore
    .collection("Items")
    .document("Factory exit key(Factory)")
    .collection("TheKeyOpens");
```

Comment: I found a similar question, and they explained it more clearly than I did, the whole problem is that `.document ()` is dynamic and the identifier of this `document` is already set, I need to go to` TurnTheKeyOpens` to open a collection with the name "TheKeyOpens" if it is there. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52461506/id-dynamic-document-firestore)

Comment: Yes, that's why I said, that you should add to the document() method the ID you have in the database.